# Teamspeak + Mariadb - Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, teamspeak

I have had a few crashes on my TS3 server since switching from SQLite to MariaDB, unfortunately they are now almost daily. Does anyone know this error and what I'm doing wrong?

The logs are for the crash on 2022-07-22 at 19:12:45 34.
The logs 3 seconds after the crash show a normal server start and reconnection of 57 users in one second.

If you need more information do not hesitate to ask
Greetings LFS96

My Docker Versions:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:03:11 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:17 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
Docker Compose version v2.6.0
```

My DockerComposeFile:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  teamspeak:
    image: teamspeak:latest
    container_name: teamspeak
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "***/teamspeak:/var/ts3server/"
      - "***/licensekey.dat:/var/ts3server/licensekey.dat"
    ports:
      - 9987:9987/udp
      - 10011:10011
      - 30033:30033
    environment:
      TS3SERVER_DB_PLUGIN: ts3db_mariadb
      TS3SERVER_DB_SQLCREATEPATH: create_mariadb
      TS3SERVER_DB_HOST: db
      TS3SERVER_DB_USER: root
      TS3SERVER_DB_PASSWORD: *********
      TS3SERVER_DB_NAME: teamspeak
      TS3SERVER_DB_WAITUNTILREADY: 30
      TS3SERVER_LICENSE: accept
      TS3SERVER_DB_CONNECTIONS: 20
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: teamspeak-db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "***/teamspeak-db:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: **************
      MYSQL_DATABASE: teamspeak
```

Logs of Mariadb:

```
2022-07-20 07:17:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.8.3+maria~jammy started.
2022-07-20 07:17:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-07-20 07:17:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.8.3+maria~jammy started.
2022-07-20 07:17:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] mariadbd (server 10.8.3-MariaDB-1:10.8.3+maria~jammy) starting as process 1 ...
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Warning] mariadbd: io_uring_queue_init() failed with ENOSYS: check seccomp filters, and the kernel version (newer than 5.1 required)
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Warning] InnoDB: liburing disabled: falling back to innodb_use_native_aio=OFF
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 221395821; transaction id 52866
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220720  7:17:49
2022-07-20  7:17:49 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.8.3-MariaDB-1:10.8.3+maria~jammy'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2022-07-21 17:12:02 23 [Warning] Aborted connection 23 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 22 [Warning] Aborted connection 22 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 21 [Warning] Aborted connection 21 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 19 [Warning] Aborted connection 19 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 20 [Warning] Aborted connection 20 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 17 [Warning] Aborted connection 17 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 18 [Warning] Aborted connection 18 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 14 [Warning] Aborted connection 14 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 16 [Warning] Aborted connection 16 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 15 [Warning] Aborted connection 15 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 13 [Warning] Aborted connection 13 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 12 [Warning] Aborted connection 12 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 11 [Warning] Aborted connection 11 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 7 [Warning] Aborted connection 7 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 4 [Warning] Aborted connection 4 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 5 [Warning] Aborted connection 5 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 6 [Warning] Aborted connection 6 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 8 [Warning] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 9 [Warning] Aborted connection 9 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-21 17:12:02 10 [Warning] Aborted connection 10 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 43 [Warning] Aborted connection 43 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 25 [Warning] Aborted connection 25 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 40 [Warning] Aborted connection 40 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 42 [Warning] Aborted connection 42 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 39 [Warning] Aborted connection 39 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 44 [Warning] Aborted connection 44 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 38 [Warning] Aborted connection 38 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 37 [Warning] Aborted connection 37 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 36 [Warning] Aborted connection 36 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 35 [Warning] Aborted connection 35 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 34 [Warning] Aborted connection 34 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 33 [Warning] Aborted connection 33 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 32 [Warning] Aborted connection 32 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 31 [Warning] Aborted connection 31 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 30 [Warning] Aborted connection 30 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 29 [Warning] Aborted connection 29 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 28 [Warning] Aborted connection 28 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 27 [Warning] Aborted connection 27 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 26 [Warning] Aborted connection 26 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2022-07-22 19:12:45 41 [Warning] Aborted connection 41 to db: 'teamspeak' user: 'root' host: '172.31.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

TS3 Serverlog:
The ServerProtector loginfails, are me with the wrong password.

```
2022-07-21 17:12:04.820917|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |TeamSpeak 3 Server 3.13.7 (2022-06-20 12:21:53)
2022-07-21 17:12:04.821276|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |SystemInformation: Linux 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64 Binary: 64bit
2022-07-21 17:12:04.821342|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |Using hardware aes
2022-07-21 17:12:04.823583|INFO    |DatabaseQuery |   |dbPlugin name:    MariaDB plugin, version 3, (c)TeamSpeak Systems GmbH
2022-07-21 17:12:04.823695|INFO    |DatabaseQuery |   |dbPlugin version: 2
2022-07-21 17:12:04.893830|INFO    |Accounting    |   |Licensing Information
2022-07-21 17:12:04.893950|INFO    |Accounting    |   |licensed to       : ***
2022-07-21 17:12:04.894028|INFO    |Accounting    |   |type              : Activation License
2022-07-21 17:12:04.894121|INFO    |Accounting    |   |starting date     : *** 2022
2022-07-21 17:12:04.894178|INFO    |Accounting    |   |ending date       : *** 2023
2022-07-21 17:12:04.894214|INFO    |Accounting    |   |max virtualservers: 2
2022-07-21 17:12:04.894376|INFO    |Accounting    |   |max slots         : 128
2022-07-21 17:12:05.701148|INFO    |              |   |Puzzle precompute time: 765
2022-07-21 17:12:05.704537|INFO    |FileManager   |   |listening on 0.0.0.0:30033, [::]:30033
2022-07-21 17:12:05.708987|INFO    |Query         |   |Using a query thread pool size of 2
2022-07-21 17:12:05.865885|INFO    |Query         |   |listening for query on 0.0.0.0:10011, [::]:10011
2022-07-21 17:12:05.866109|INFO    |CIDRManager   |   |updated query_ip_allowlist ips: 127.0.0.1/32, ::1/128, 172.26.0.1/32,
2022-07-21 17:12:37.075323|INFO    |              |   |Increased protection level to: 1
2022-07-21 17:13:42.046104|INFO    |              |   |Decreased protection level to: 0
2022-07-22 07:12:51.343922|INFO    |              |   |myTeamSpeak identifier revocation list was downloaded successfully - all related features are activated
2022-07-22 08:36:08.921909|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 270 172.31.0.4:47086 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 08:39:00.796296|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 271 172.31.0.4:47164 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 08:42:00.716925|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 272 172.31.0.4:47226 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 08:54:04.910678|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 276 172.31.0.4:47466 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 08:57:04.807830|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 277 172.31.0.4:47598 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 09:00:04.773872|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 278 172.31.0.4:47942 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 09:10:46.547001|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 282 172.31.0.4:48804 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 09:10:50.748387|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 283 172.31.0.4:48814 attempted to login with account "ServerProtector" and failed!
2022-07-22 09:12:04.926808|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 284 172.31.0.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Solved

The IP range in Docker changed so that the IP whitelist no longer matched.
This caused Teamspeak to flood and crash.

Fixed by editing the whitelist

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for "Error reading communication packets" is sloppy coding on the client side. When a client application does not tell the database server that it intends to close the connection before actually doing so the server just sees the client network connection vanish while still trying to read further queries from it.

As the database server now does not, and cannot, know whether the client closed the connection intentionally or whether this was actually caused by a network issue along the way between client and server it can only log the error.

This is controlled by the `log_warnings` level setting, if you don't want to have these warnings spam your database error log you can reduce the warnings level to 1, as these warnings are only logged at level 2 and up

Comment: Hello, this error message comes in the same second that the Teamspeak server crashes. The message does not bother me, what bothers me is that the Teamspeak crashes.